# TS Error: "Exported variable 'withCreateSomething' has or is using name 'React.ComponentClass' from external module / but can not be named"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I have a graphql mutation file:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { SomeMutationVariables, SomeMutation } from "..schemaTypes"        

const someMutation = gql`
  mutation SomeMutation(
  $something: String!
  ) {
     createSome(
     input: {
      something: $something
     }
   )
  }
 `;



    export interface NewPropsCreateSomething {
   createSomething: ( variables:  SomeMutationVariable ) => void;
    }



     export const withCreateSomething = graphql<
      any,
      SomeMutation,
      SomeMutationVariable
      NewPropsCreateSomething
    >(createSomethingMutation, {
      props: ({ mutate }) => ({
       createSomething async variables => {
     if (!mutate) {
        return;
        }

        const response = await mutate({
        variables
        } );
       console.log( "response", response )  
           }
       })
    });
```

I can not build the code because I am being thrown the error: 
"Exported variable 'withCreateSomething' has or is using name 'React.ComponentClass' from external module "/../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index" but cannot be named"

it appears that graphql is using react types;  I can eradicate the error by importing react:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

But then of course I receive this error: 
 'React' is declared but its value is never read.

I know this error has appeared in other posts, but I can't find this case addressed since this file has no react specific code,  and other than the type error,  there is no reason to import react.

I try to avoid using @ ts-ignore but so far that is the only method that allows the build to proceed.

Any pointers to an elegant solution is appreciated.

Comment: Is this the actual code you're using? `createSomething async variables => {` looks like a syntax error. Some proper indentation might help grok the code a little more easily, too. Fix any typoes and [run it through here](https://prettier.io/playground/)

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using?  TypeScript 2.9 and newer support "import types", which [are supposed to fix many errors like this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#relaxing-declaration-emit-visiblity-rules).

Comment: No this not the actual code it should be `createSomething: async variables => {}`  I am using version 2.9.2. I was not aware of the import types feature, I attempted to implement the import() feature but I am still being thrown the same error.